# some files not transferring when deploying website to azure

Tags: azure

I am in the process off trying to deploy my site to azure. I right click and select "Publish". When the site is opened automatically it seems to work but I can see some css and some files have not transferred. Looking at "Server explored" in Visual Studio it looks like many files are not there, including the home controller which was opened (so what is being shown in the files in VS has got to be wrong). I have tried refreshing my files in VS and have deployed this application several time to resolve other similar issues. What am I doing wrong?

NB: sorry if im missing some vital settings information to help diagnose this issue, im total new to azure, please ask if you need further clarifaction

Comment: Did you mark your additional (missing) content with `Copy Local = true`?

Comment: I didn't know seeing copy local=true was required. I haven't explicitly set any files. I will try but I don't understand why some would need to be explicitly set?

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use Git repository instead of VS in case u're facing any difficulties there, its totally integrated and easy to be used.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Comment: When their problem isn't much of logic (publishing files without being shown there) then you have to suggest alternatives, the goal is to solve a problem. Git on azure IS easy to use and doesnt need ANY expertise.